# How to get a scalar from polars to python without to_series.to_list()[0]

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I want to get the max of a column back to regular python variable

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
```

Right now I'm doing `df.select(pl.col('a').max()).to_series().to_list()[0]` but that's seems a bit clunky.  Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index a `DataFrame` in row, column order.

```py
>>> df.select(pl.max('a'))[0, 0]
3
```